# Physical plausibility of the Inverted Pyramid puzzle

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

The inverted pyramid puzzle has the following premises:

> A giant inverted steel pyramid is perfectly balanced on its point. 
>   Any movement of the pyramid will cause it to topple over.  Underneath
>   the pyramid is a $100 bill.  How do you remove the bill without
>   disturbing the pyramid?

The answer to puzzle is [here](http://www.questionotd.com/2010/04/are-you-feeling-greedy.html).

Physics Questions:

1. A friend, who did not provide the standard answer, claimed that the bill can be removed easily by pulling it out from underneath. I do not think this is correct if there is non-zero friction, as the mass of the pyramid would make the frictional force too great. The force of friction is independent of the area of contact, so it would be just as difficult to remove as if the pyramid was not inverted. Please confirm.
2. If we assume that the pyramid is solid steel and the size of an Egyptian pyramid, **does a human being have the strength to even move such a massive pyramid intentionally?** (I understand that *if* the pyramid was moved, it would topple over, because of the location of the center of gravity.  However, my question is whether such a pyramid can be moved by a human in the first place. A very tall styrofoam column can be toppled easily, but an iron column of the same dimensions may be unmovable, due to the difference in mass.)

*Note: Your answers should not try to solve the puzzle. The physics question is whether the premise of the puzzle is physically plausible.*

Comment: _If we assume that the pyramid is solid steel and the size of an Egyptian pyramid, does a human being have the strength to even move such a massive pyramid intentionally?_ In real life you would be smashed by the pyramid (no need to tuch it). But if you suppose there is no friction you could pick the bill without moving the pyramid, although you would die by asphyxia.

Comment: But if we assume there is some friction, then wouldn't the frictional force (due to the pyramid's mass) be so great that you cannot move either the bill or the pyramid? Or you would rip the bill?

Comment: Rip the bill in two, leaving only a very thin strip of paper where the pyramid top is resting. Take the two pieces to a bank where they can examine it, and then they reimburse you a new one. Since the strip is very thin, due to thinness of the pyramid top, the bill will have all the serial numbers intact.

Comment: Idealy, a nonzero force would make the pyramid fall (unless the pyramid has infinite mass). So even the collision of an atom would be enough. Of course, in real life the situation would be impossible (the pyramid would be buried or something like that).

Comment: @jinawee - Can you prove that a nonzero force would make the pyramid fall? The Leaning Tower of Pisa is unstable, but even without reinforcements, it is not that any nonzero force can topple it.

Comment: The Tower of Pisa has foundations underneath, although they are very bad (just 3 meters).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a brainteaser that has little to do with physics.

Comment: You should stress that the question is not the brainsteaser, but if you can make the pyramid fall.

Comment: I have updated the question to stress that the question is not the brainteaser. Why am I being voted down?

Comment: I think there is a basic physics question here, regarding linear stability analysis in classical mechanics. That said, phrasing the question in the context of the brainteaser is probably the reason for the down/close votes - we have seen all too many "solve my homework" and "this isn't physics but I want to hear what physicists say" questions lately, and so there's a certain knee-jerk reaction to anything vaguely resembling this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In high-school level classical mechanics, yes, you are told the maximum magnitude of static friction is simply a coefficient $\mu_\mathrm{s}$ (depending on the materials) times the magnitude of the normal force, $F_\mathrm{N}$. This is independent of area because the smaller the area, the greater the contact pressure and so the more interlocked the uneven surfaces become, meaning more static friction per unit area. Thus sliding the inverted pyramid will not be feasible in this model.

In reality this nice area-independence would probably break down for such high pressure. Coefficients of static friction are recognized as cute toy models suitable for high school but they are not terribly accurate in the real world. In physics language, you have moved beyond the linear regime.

More interesting is the idea of tipping the pyramid over. It may be perfectly balanced, yes, but it is in *unstable equilibrium*. That is, classically, even the smallest perturbation to the system will grow in a positive feedback loop. Unless your model specifies that there is a static friction *torque* at the apex, a slight push will angle the pyramid slighty, and then gravity will take the whole thing down for you. This is true no matter how much inertia the object has (even though it may not seem like it - you have to mentally separate notions of "arbitrarily small effect" and "zero effect").

Answer (score 0):

Construct 4 pillars, or however many of them you would see fit to support the weight of a steel pyramid, under the pyramid itself. Then start digging where the bill is until the entire weight is transferred to the pillars and the apex is left hanging over a small hole in the ground.

Comment: I have updated the question to stress that the brainteaser is not the point of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Wait for a quantum fluctuation and flash pull out the Benny.

Nothing in the puzzle says the bill must be preserved, only that it must be removed.  Wet it with an aqueous solution of cellulase.  Dissolve it in DMSO/Bu4N(+) F(-), DMSO/Et3N/SO2, DMSO/paraformaldehyde, ionic liquids, dimethylacetamide/LiCl, aqueous NaOH plus CS2, N-methylmorpholine N-oxide, aqueous Cu(ethylenediamine)2, ammonium thiocyanate plus ammonia, guanidinium hydroxide.

Wet with liquid oxygen, slightly warm until dry, ignite.

The pyramid, if it has a sharp or rounded point, spontaneously topples.  Consider a pendulum of length 1 and mass 1.  Specify the orientation by the angle, $x(t)$, measured from the position with the bob vertically below the suspension point.  The potential energy is

$V = g * (1-\cos x) = 2g * (\sin\frac{x}{2})^2$

Set the initial conditions 
$x(0) = 0, x'(0) = 2g$

The energy
$E = \frac{1}{2} (x')^2 + 2g * (\sin \frac{x}{2})^2$
$\frac{dx}{dt} = \sqrt{4g [1 - (\sin \frac{x}{2})^2]}$

Then  
$dt = \sqrt{\frac{1}{4g(1-\sin^2\frac{x}{2})^2}} dx$

The integral of $dx$ from $x = 0$ to $x = a$ diverges as $a \to \pi$.